# Android apk: install emulator then device

Tags: android

Okay so i have been working on this app for a couple months now not really sure what i have done... but before when i would run the app from eclipse to the emulator it would auto open the application when it is finished loading it.. now it doesn't,, then after i signed the app and put the apk file onto my sd card and then installed it, it shows that it has been installed but doesn't show up in the app drawer and i can't run in from the setting>manage apps.... anyone have an idea what i might of done that has messed it up?

**UPDATE 12-11-2011**

after looking into the manifest i found the simple problem that was like a thorn to me, this is what i had that was causing the error:

```
<activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`android:name=".Splash"` intent should of been `android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"`

then changed my class Main to MainScreen that intent then should of been `android:name="android.intent.action.MAINSCREEN"`
so i wouldn't confuse myself (hopefully) anymore on it

Comment: have you tried uninstalling it, then reinstalling it?

Comment: yea that's when it doesn't show up in with the apps, today i tried reinstalling a apk file that i had working and then installed this newer version and it worked fine  so i think **Jakar** might be on to something gotta check that out to make sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `manifest.xml` file there should be one activity similar to this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="My Awesome App">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The notable part is the `intent-filter`. If you don't have that setup correctly, then it will not show in the app drawer. My guess is that you removed that by accident somehow...

Comment: now on the action what is better?
**A)** android.intent.action.MAIN
**B)** com.pack.app.MAIN

I've seen it done both ways in tutorials and examples

Comment: Jakar, thanks for your answer it turned me in the direction i needed to go to figure this out lol. I hate it when the simplest things can stump you

Comment: You should use `android.intent.action.MAIN`. That's what the Android docs say (as far as I know). And I know what you mean. The simplest things generally seem to give me the most trouble because they're so easy to miss.